# Using "set -eux pipefail" in docker CMD

Tags: docker, sh

I have simple dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
```

This is my docker run command

```bash
docker run <container-name> \
sh -c """set -eux pipefail && \
temp | sed 's/temp/perma/g'"""
```

This is the output

```bash
+ temp
sh: temp: not found
+ sed s/temp/perma/g
```

But, the return code of the above docker run is 0.

Even though I have a pipefail using `set`, why does docker return 0?

Though not shown here, if there were any subsequent commands after the sed command which were chained with `&&`, they will be executed.

Why does `set -eux pipefail` not work ?

Comment: `pipefail` is an `-o`ption, `set -euxo pipefail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that one of the things that makes Alpine small is that it doesn't include the full GNU tool set you normally get on Linux, but instead a minimal implementation called [BusyBox](https://busybox.net).  When you're using the shell, you get what's supported in the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) but not much more.

In particular, POSIX-standard [**set**(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) doesn't support bash's `pipefail` option.

As noted in a comment, you also need a `-o` option to specify long-form shell options.  Without `-o`, this has the effect of setting positional arguments instead.

```shellsession
$ docker run --rm alpine \
    sh -c 'echo "one: $1"; set -eux pipefail; echo "one: $1"'
+ echo 'one: pipefail'
one:
one: pipefail
```

If you really need extended GNU bash functionality, you need to `apk add bash` to install bash, or to use a base image like `debian` or `ubuntu` that already includes it.  Make sure to explicitly say `bash -c` or `#!/bin/bash` so you're specifying the right shell.